# Linking local react components together other than using gitlab/github

Tags: reactjs, package.json, react-component

I am working on making a react app and it has some dependencies on other repository. Till now it is linked in the following way shown in dependecies from gitlab. I want to download that repo locally and want to link it locally instead of using git+ssh. If anyone has any suggestion please let me know. REPO name has been changed to maintain confidentiality.

This is a package.json file of my app( The one I am working on)

````
    "name": "test-webapp",
    "version": "1.1.66",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "COMPONENT-NAME": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/REPO_NAME.git#master",
        "universal-cookie": "^3.1.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not ie <= 11",
        "not op_mini all"
    ]
}```
````